# Any Support for Matlab or octave in intellij

Tags: matlab, intellij-idea, octave, intellij-plugin

I code in Matlab/octave very often. While having several good features it lacks a good editor. 
My question is that is there any other good editor for it. My preference is intellij Idea, which is one the best IDEs I've ever tried. In this regard, can I connect octave or matlab to intellij (e.g. via some plugins)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've implemented Matlab plugin for IntelliJ:
https://github.com/kornilova-l/matlab-IntelliJ-plugin
It has syntax highlighting, resolve, rename and autocompletion.
I continue development so submit an issue on GitHub if you miss some feature or you found a bug

Comment: That's great. Can I compile Matlab with it now?

Comment: please let me know if you completed the development.

Comment: @Hamid, no, currently plugin has only lexer, I've created an issue in the GitHub repo about running files from IDE, so I'll do it sometime in future

Comment: @Hamid, it's possible to run .m files from IDE in version 0.2. Also I fixed string highlighting

Comment: Thanks. That would be great if you add autocomplete and live template features as well!

Answer (score 1):

For octave support, you could use the textmate bundle support.

Install the Textmate Bundle Support plugin first and then follow the instructions here on how to add any textmate bundle.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-textmate-bundles.html

This here is a matlab/octave bundle that you could then use.

https://github.com/textmate/matlab.tmbundle

Comment: That worked. But, how can I have autocomplete feature and Matlab run in the IntelliJ too?

Comment: @Hamid sorry but that is the best alternative I could find.

Comment: Sure, but there should be a way for introducing path folders to IntelliJ so that the namespace of the IntelliJ will be modified

Comment: @Sudhir, After installing the TextMate bundle plugin in pycharm, I can't see how & where to install the octave instructions? any suggestion?

Comment: @anu the instructions are available at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/tutorial-using-textmate-bundles.html under the "Importing Bundles" section. Octave is mostly compatible with matlab. So the matlab support should work.

Answer (score 0):

for **Octave** 
https://github.com/tomconder/octaveplugin 
https://github.com/demongoo/idea-octave-plugin 
https://github.com/idkravitz/octave-idea-plugin

**UPDATE:**

thanks **@GameOfThrows** 
I confused Wolframs Mathematica with Matlab. Look like **at the moment there is no MatLab plugin**  for IntelliJ

this is for Mathematica:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7232-mathematica-support

Comment: Mathematica is not really Matlab, there's no support from jetbrains on Matlab

Comment: It seems that non of the above works properly for matlab!

Comment: Has anybody installed any of them? does they work properly?

Comment: How to install them? no documentation at all!

Comment: Hamid, unfortunately no I havent. But this could be helpful i think https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/deploying_plugin.html