# Defining path for the auto-completion of MATLAB plugin for IntelliJ

Tags: matlab, intellij-idea

Having asked about [Matlab plugin for IntelliJ by me](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46338589/7328782), one of the Jetbrains employees implemented such a plugin:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10941-matlab-support

My question is how can I define the Matlab path for autocompletion in this plugin. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That plugin only does code highlighting, and it can start up MATLAB with the `-r` switch to run an M-file that you have open in the editor. It does not do any autocompletion, code formatting, etc.

The MATLAB editor does all of these things and more. I wish the editor part was better. :)

Comment: @Hamid: Yes, it's a great editor, I use CLion every day. The MATAB editor is a shitty editor. But it does autocompletion, code formatting, navigation, linting, debugging, etc., and there are no other editors out there can can do those things as well for MATLAB code.

Comment: Lyudmila Kornilova started a development here: https://github.com/kornilova-l/matlab-IntelliJ-plugin. we may be able to contribute to have it ready

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46338589/any-support-for-matlab-or-octave-in-intellij

Comment: @Hamid: Indeed. If you manage to extend the plugin to do code formatting and autocompletion, let me know! :)